# How to specify DateTime in GraphQL schema?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java, typegraphql

I am building my GraphQL schema for my project and one of my models has a DateTime format.

How do I write out date formats on my GraphQL schema?

I tried DateTime or Date but nothing shows up.

This is the model:

```
public Integer Id;
public String name;
public String description;
public LocalDate birthDate;
```

This is what's in my GraphQL schema:

```
type Pet {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String
    birthDate: DateTime
}
```

But it says:

> Unknown type DateTime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date and Json in type definition for graphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693928/date-and-json-in-type-definition-for-graphql)

Comment: Another approach, mentioned in a comment, is to "_directly store dates as time in millis_" (milliseconds since the epoch). Look at Java's [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). BUT I don't know if epoch-seconds would fit into a GraphQL primitive - so that may not help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom scalar for your types that is not recognized by your framework.

I am not sure which graphql-java based framework you are using. I assume you are using the official [Spring for GraphQL](https://spring.io/projects/spring-graphql) from Spring team.

1. Create a custom scalar, eg [my LocalDateTime scalar](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-graphql-sample/blob/master/spring-graphql/src/main/java/com/example/demo/gql/scalars/LocalDateTimeScalar.java).

   public class LocalDateTimeScalar implements Coercing<LocalDateTime, String> {
   @Override
   public String serialize(Object dataFetcherResult) throws CoercingSerializeException {
   if (dataFetcherResult instanceof LocalDateTime) {
   return ((LocalDateTime) dataFetcherResult).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
   } else {
   throw new CoercingSerializeException("Not a valid DateTime");
   }
   }

   ```
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime parseValue(Object input) throws CoercingParseValueException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(input.toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime parseLiteral(Object input) throws CoercingParseLiteralException {
        if (input instanceof StringValue) {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(((StringValue) input).getValue(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
        }

        throw new CoercingParseLiteralException("Value is not a valid ISO date time");
    }
   ```

   }
2. Register it in your custom `RuntimeWiring` bean, check [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-graphql-sample/blob/master/spring-graphql/src/main/java/com/example/demo/gql/PostsRuntimeWiring.java#L41).

   ```java
   public class Scalars {

       public static GraphQLScalarType localDateTimeType() {
           return GraphQLScalarType.newScalar()
                   .name("LocalDateTime")
                   .description("LocalDateTime type")
                   .coercing(new LocalDateTimeScalar())
                   .build();
       }
   }
   ```

   ```java
   @Component
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class PostsRuntimeWiring implements RuntimeWiringConfigurer {
       private final DataFetchers dataFetchers;

       @Override
       public void configure(RuntimeWiring.Builder builder) {
           builder
                   //...
                   .scalar(Scalars.localDateTimeType())
                   //...
                   .build();
       }
   }
   ```

If you are using Scalars in other graphql-java based frameworks(GraphQL Java, GraphQL Java Kickstart, GraphQL Kotlin, GraphQL SPQR, Netflix DGS etc) and spring integrations, check my [Spring GraphQL Sample](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-graphql-sample). The back-end principle is similar, just some different config.