# Appsync "Variable 'timestamp' has an invalid value."

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am stuck on the simple task of uploading a timestamp via AppSync.

I have made this test schema for easy demonstration:

```
type Mutation {
    testCreateCar(input: TestCreateCarInput!): TestCar
        @aws_cognito_user_pools
}

type TestCar {
    regno: String!
    country: String!
    timestamp: Int
}

input TestCreateCarInput {
    regno: String!
    country: String!
    timestamp: Int
}
```

This is my resolver:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key" : {
        "regno": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.regno),
        "country": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.country),
    },
    "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args)
}
```

This is the function in my FE that makes the request:

```
export const createCar = async (carData: Car) => { 
    try {
        await client.graphql({
            query: mutations.testCreateCar,
            variables: { input: {
                regno: carData.regno,
                country: carData.country,
                timestamp: Date.now()
            } }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
};
```

When I try and upload a car I get the following error:

"Variable 'timestamp' has an invalid value."

How can this be? The Date.now() returns a number and I have clearly specified that "timestamp" is of type number in my schema.

Much appreciated for your time, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema, you declare your timestamp is of 'Int' type. Current unix timestamp (which is what `Date.now()` returns) as of today is 1708650175742, which is more then an Int value can handle (INT_MAX is 2147483647).

You will probably want to use a custom type for it - don't know what exact graphql you are using, but there are a lot of solutions available (e.g. [graphql-iso-date](https://github.com/excitement-engineer/graphql-iso-date) as part of [graphql-scalars package](https://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-scalars)). There are some other links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693928/date-and-json-in-type-definition-for-graphql) (and one of the answers describes how to make your own).

Alternatively, if this is a one-time-demo that you will never need for real... Just have your car be made in Jan 1970 (`Date.parse('12 Jan 1970 12:00:00 GMT')` instead of `Date.now()`), so that the unix timestamp is small enough to fit into an int:)